# writing to a vector< vector<bool> >

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, boolean

I'm writing for class an implementation of Conway's Game of Life in a toroid. The function `cargarToroide` (loadToroid) should load from a file into the vector the appropriate status (alive or dead - True or False - 1 or 0) of each cell (`celda`), it's signature is as follows:

```
toroide cargarToroide(string nombreArchivo, bool &status);
```

`nombreArchivo` is the name of the file, and `status` should be false if there is any problem loading the file or in the format of the file.

The data structure is defined like this (I cannot change it):

```
typedef vector< vector<bool> > toroide;
```

the file is structured like this:

```
numberOfLines numberOfColums
list of the values of the cells
number of live cells
```

For example:

```
4 4
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0
4
```

The thing is, I cannot find a way to make it work. I've read online that `vector<bool>` has problems when you try to load it the usual way, which was the first thing I've tried.

```
toroide cargarToroide(string nombreArchivo, bool &status)
{
    toroide t;
    ifstream fi (nombreArchivo);
    int cantidadFilas, cantidadColumnas;
    int celda;

    if(!fi){
        status = false;
    }

    fi >> cantidadFilas;
    fi >> cantidadColumnas;

    for(int i = 0; i < cantidadFilas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cantidadColumnas; j++) {
            fi >> celda;
            if(celda == 1) {
                t[i].push_back(true);
            }
            else if(celda == 0){
                t[i].push_back(false);
            }
            else{
                status = false;
                return t;
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

I've also tried defining `celda` as a boolean and just using

```
t[i].push_back(celda);
```

What would be the best way to approach this using C++11?

Comment: In what way does it not work? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: I notice you never set `status` to `true`.

Comment: I've then tried to print the vector and it failed (a 1 if true, a 0 if false). When I checked using a dubbuger I get a segmentation fault when the execution reaches the push_back line, but that does not appear when I compile it normally.

Comment: In what way did it fail? Show the code that prints the vector, the output thus produced, and explain how that output differs from your expectations.

Comment: Before the inner loop: `vector<bool> row; t.push_back(row)`

Comment: Ah. `t` is an empty vector; `t[i]` exhibits undefined behavior for any value of `i`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds. Before the loops, add `t.resize(cantidadFilas);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, you are right, i've forgoten to do that. But that shoudn't affect the loading problem. (about setting `status` to `true`)

Comment: IgorTandetnik, JohnnyMopp: thank you. both solutions work. Is one of them better than the other in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know  the number of rows at compile time (as you do in this case) you can use `resize`. In this case you will have to do the below **before** both the `for` loops.

```
t.resize(cantidadFilas);
```

In fact, you can do the same for the columns as well. Then you would no longer need to use `push_back` in the inner `for` loop as well.

If do not know the number of rows then you will just use `push_back` and add the rows to `toroide`. Then you would add the below lines before the second `for` loop.

```
vector<bool> row; 
t.push_back(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to resize the outer vector before you can use operator[] on it. You should also use the proper type (bool) when reading the data and check the input file for errors. I've commented in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector< std::vector<bool> > toroide;

// Both cargarToroide and cargarToroide_improved can be used
bool cargarToroide_improved(const std::string& nombreArchivo, toroide& in_toroide)
{
    std::ifstream fi(nombreArchivo);
    if(!fi) return false;

    int cantidadFilas, cantidadColumnas, liveCells=0;
    // use a bool to read the bool data
    bool celda;

    fi >> cantidadFilas;
    fi >> cantidadColumnas;
    // check if the stream is in a failed state
    if(fi.fail()) return false;

    // Temporary used to not mess with in_toroide until we're finished.
    // Create it with cantidadFilas default inserted rows
    toroide t(cantidadFilas);

    for(auto& row : t) {
        // default insert columns into the row
        row.resize(cantidadColumnas);
        for (int col = 0; col < cantidadColumnas; ++col) {
            fi >> celda;
            // check if the stream is in a failed state
            // (non-bool read or the file reached eof())
            if(fi.fail()) return false;
            // set column value in the row
            row[col] = celda;
            // count live cells
            liveCells += celda;
        }
    }

    // compare live cells in matrix with checksum
    int cmpLive;
    fi >> cmpLive;
    if(fi.fail() || cmpLive!=liveCells) return false;

    // a successful toroide was read, swap your temporary
    // toroide with the user supplied one
    std::swap(t, in_toroide);
    return true;
}

// if the signature of this function really can't be changed (which it should),
// make it a proxy for the function with a slightly nicer interface
// Like this:
toroide cargarToroide(std::string nombreArchivo, bool &status)
{
    toroide rv;
    status = cargarToroide_improved(nombreArchivo, rv);
    return rv;
}
```

Using the improved signature:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);

    for(auto& file : args) {
        toroide my_toroide;
        if(cargarToroide_improved(file, my_toroide)) {
            for(auto& r : my_toroide) {
                for(auto c : r) {
                    std::cout << c << " ";
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::clog << "failed loading " << file << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Using the signature you're forced to use:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);

    for(auto& file : args) {
        bool status;
        toroide my_toroide = cargarToroide(file, status);
        if(status) {
            for(auto& r : my_toroide) {
                for(auto c : r) {
                    std::cout << c << " ";
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::clog << "failed loading " << file << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't change the signature of the function as I'm not the one calling it. But I've implemented some of your ideas. `liveCells` is a check to see if the file was corrupted, so i've to simply count the amount of live cells readed and compare with that.

Comment: Ok, I made changes to reflect the constraints on the signature, but I think you should argue to change it. It becomes much easier to use if you do. I also added checking that the liveCells are correct.